# Ordering objects by a sum of has_many association. Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tests
end

class Test <ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

I need to sort all users by the sum of scores on the test, only for last 7 days.

For all time i am use:

```
User.joins(:tests).group(:user_id).order("sum(tests.score) DESC")
```

How sort users by sum score only for tests created_at last 7 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with this

```
User.joins(:tests).where('tests.created_at >= ?', 1.week.ago).group(:user_id).order("sum(tests.score) DESC")
```